# add overflow auto to an absolute positioned div

Tags: html, css

I have a menu and sidebar which are positioned fixed and a main area positioned absolute

What I want to achieve is to set a min-width to the content inside the main area, and have scrollbar x and y on it so I can navigate inside it

I tried to add `overflow:auto` to the `#main` and `overflow:hidden` to the `body` but scroll-bars are not showing inside #main, I am not sure what I am doing wrong :

this is the jsfiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/mody5/Lhc3fbke/

and this is the code :

```
<div id="sidebar">Sidebar</div>

<div id="menu">Menu</div>

<div id="main">

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

css :

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}

body{
    overflow: hidden;
}
#sidebar{
    width: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    background: blue;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    padding-top: 100px;
}

#menu{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
    color:white;
    z-index: 9999;
}

#main{
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    top: 50px;
    right: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 1400px;
    height: 100%;

    overflow: auto;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was the main div not overflowing, but just exempting the borders of the window. It was just larger.

You should set the main's borders to the window borders (changing also `height:100%` to `bottom:0` because the first was bottom-lowerflowing), and add the scrollable div inside the main with the *free* dimensions (i.e. they can be large), like this:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#sidebar {
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  background: blue;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  padding-top: 100px;
}
#menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  z-index: 9999;
}
#main {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 50px;
  right: 0;
  bottom:0;
  overflow: scroll;
}
#scrollable {
  min-width: 1400px;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">Sidebar</div>

<div id="menu">Menu</div>

<div id="main">
  <div id="scrollable">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: awesome, can you please explain what was the problem with my initial code and what you did to solve that

Comment: @medBo made a small edit, but actually I've already tried to explain.

Comment: thank you for the edit, but I still a little confusing, by "set the main's borders to the window borders" do you mean `right:0;bottom:0;` ?  and why it's necessarily to add the scrollable div inside the main ?

Comment: @medBo main's borders shouldn't exceed the window borders. Why? Because main is actually a smaller window, and scrollable is the content of it. As you can imagine, content can't exist without the window it's prisoned into. Just imagine the browser page without the window - it's not possible.

Comment: In short, the browser didnt know its content exceeds the window borders, therefore it "thought" nothing to be scrolled. By forcing content to be in the "main",  which bounds the window, we tell the browser the content is actually bigger than the window and does overflow.

Comment: humm interesting...  it's the first time I am facing this issue and it's the first time I am understanding the overflow better. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Just **FORCE** that behavior, try this:

```
<div id="main" style="overflow:scroll !important">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```